# Capture all digits (spelled out) any size with no trailing/leading space

Tags: regex

I am trying to capture all possible (spelled-out) digits except I can't seem to write an expression that captures without a trailing/preceding space.

"If there are Nineteen thousand forty-six bears"

Result: "Nineteen thousand forty-six_"   Desired: "Nineteen thousand forty-six"

Current expression:

```
\b((eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|sixteen|seventeen|eighteen|nineteen|twenty|thirty|forty|fifty|sixty|seventy|eighty|ninety|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|hundred|thousand|million|billion|trillion|and){1}([\–\-\—\‒]|\s){0,1})+\b
```

I've also tested this concept from a different post:

```
\b(?:(?:one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|zero)\b\s*?){4}
```

Which works great however it requires you to know the size before hand.

Any help would be great, I really want to capture it precisely.

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: Try `(your_number_list)(\s*(your_number_list))+`, where `your_number_list` is that your bug **OR** list with all possible number-words. However it is **NOT** task for the regexp in my opinion.

Comment: I am using Perl regexp

Comment: You regex matches `Nineteen thousand forty-six `. I don't see the last dash being captured.

Comment: @PedroLobito I'm using it as an indicator of white space sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Why not just use trim?

Comment: Also as an aside are long or lists highly inefficient in regular expressions? I feel by qualifying the exact number and not using * or + that it wouldn't be overwhelmingly slow.  I realize it won't be snappy.

Comment: @PedroLobito For visual cleanliness reasons for usability trim is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid to trim your result, instead of writing your pattern like this: `(?: item separator)+`, you can use this structure: `item (?: separator item)*`.

To do that when "item" is long, you can refer to a subpattern in a capture group using this syntax `(?n)`, where n is the number of the capture group. Example:

```
(?xi) # switch on the free-spacing mode and the case-insensitive mode
\b
(    # capture group 1
    eleven|twelve|thirt(?:y|een)|four(?:teen)?|fift(?:y|een)|six(?:teen|ty)?|
    seven(?:teen|ty)?|eight(?:een|y)?|nine(?:teen|ty)?|twenty|forty|one|two|three|five|
    ten|hundred|thousand|(?:[mb]|tr)illion
)
(?>
    (?:[-–—‒]|\s(?:and\s)?)
    (?1) # call to the subpattern in the capture group 1
)*
\b
```

Obviously you can also rewrite the subpattern in place of `(?1)` too.

As an aside, you can minimize the impact of a long alternation if you write it as a tree and using the first character discrimination technique:

```
(?xi)
\b
(?=[befhmnost][ehilnoruw])
(
    e(?:leven|ight(?:een|y)?) |
    t(?:w(?:o|e(?:lve|nty))|h(?:irt(?:een|y)|ousand|ree)|en|rillion) |
    f(?:o(?:ur(?:teen)?|rty)|i(?:ft(?:een|y)|ve)) |
    s(?:ix(?:t(?:een|y))?|even(?:t(?:een|y))?) |
    nine(?:t(?:een|y))? |
    one |
    hundred |
    [mb]illion
)
(?> (?:[-–—‒]|\s(?:and\s)?) (?1) )*
\b
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/uD8iE3/1)

Comment: Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Wow the tree approach is more than 3 times as efficient (in terms of steps) at capturing the same phrase.  That is a great technique thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a positive look-ahead `(?= )`

For example `((one|two|three|four|and)[- ]{0,1})+(?= )`

will match the text in bold without the trailing space.

Foo bar **one two-four and three** yada.

And if the number text may be at the end of a sentence you can adapt the positive look-ahead to `(?= .)`

This will also match the bold without either trailing space or "."

Foo bar **one two-four and three** yada.

Foo bar **one two-four and three**.

Comment: Nice idea.  I suppose using this method i'd have to include exceptions for any immediately trailing punctuation such as "eight, nine, ".  Also in cases of double spaces like "one two  " it may still trigger the tagging of the extra space because it still meets the look ahead requirement.